# how to correct my stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am using this code for stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE  `pmod_db`.`regmee2`(img2 varchar(200), usrnme varchar(20),
 psswrd varchar(50), frstnme varchar(50),lstnme varchar(50),email varchar(255))
BEGIN
insert into IMAGES (image_url) values (img2);
insert into dbo_users (user_name,password,firstname,lastname,email) values
(usrnme,psswrd,frstnme,lstnme,email);
insert into user_images (userid ,image_id ) select u.user_id ,i.image_id from dbo_users u ,images i where user_id=(select user_id from dbo_users where user_name=usrnme ) and image_id=(select image_id from images where image_url=img2);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting following error

```
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
 your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'STORED PROCEDURE CREATE 
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pmod_db`.`regmee'
 at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pointing you to exactly where the syntax problem is.  The command is [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx), not `CREATE STORED PROCEDURE`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the wrong command for creating procedure as @David mentioned in his answer, if `image_id` and `user_id` are both `auto_increment` columns then you most likely want to use [`LAST_INSERT-_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) instead of subqueries to fetch the id's

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE  `pmod_db`.`regmee2`
(
    img2    VARCHAR(200), 
    usrnme  VARCHAR(20),
    psswrd  VARCHAR(50), 
    frstnme VARCHAR(50),
    lstnme  VARCHAR(50),
    email   VARCHAR(255)
 )
BEGIN
    DECLARE _image_id, _user_id INT;

    INSERT INTO images (image_url) values (img2);
    SET _image_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO dbo_users (user_name, password, firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES (usrnme, psswrd, frstnme, lstnme, email);
    SET _user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO user_images (userid, image_id) 
    VALUES (_user_id, _image_id);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5d9a8/1)** demo